# CodeIgniter Query Get Where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following:

```
/** Load necessary stuff **/
        $this->load->helper('date');

        $this->db->get('site_requests');
        //echo mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now());
        //die;
        $this->db->where("(created_for <= " . "'2019-04-24 18:47:03'" . ")");
        $this->db->get();
        print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

But I receive the following:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (`created_for` <= '2019-04-24 18:47:03')' at line 2

SELECT * WHERE (`created_for` <= '2019-04-24 18:47:03')

Filename: modules/sound/models/Sound_request_model.php

Line Number: 35
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can put it into one statement

```
    $this->db->get_where('site_requests', array('created_for <=', '2019-04-24 18:47:03'));
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

You will need to chain ->result() or result_array() or any outputting function to get the data return.

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where("(created_for <= " . "'2019-04-24 18:47:03'" . ")");
```

should be after

```
$this->db->get('site_requests');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the key-value form:

`$this->db->where("created_for <=", "2019-04-24 18:47:03");`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing defining the `FROM` part of query.
I think you just need to change your code:

```
    $query = $this->db->from('site_requests')
       ->where("(created_for <= " . "'2019-04-24 18:47:03'" . ")")
       ->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    print_r($result);
```